# Concatenate row and column titles

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to populate a table with the concatenation of rows and columns titles as attached, from:

[image]

The problem is that number of rows and columns can change.

Comment: Where are the names (Alan, James, Catherine) coming from?

Comment: Hello, column A that i missed on the screenshots. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

There is no VBA required for this. A simple formula can do it.

Assuming that the names (Alan, James, Catherine, etc.) are in column A and that the positions are in column B and the countries are in column C.

Assuming that the years are in row 2 and the months are in row 3.

Enter the following formula into cell D4:

```
=$A4&";"&$B4&";"&$C4&";"&D$3&";"&D$2
```

Now copy D4 downward and rightward as far as you need.

That's it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However i need to do it in vba as headers shiuld be populated freely by users. About the names they come from colum A that i missed during the screenshot.

Comment: @Aslaam I understand VBA very well, but I do not understand what you mean. Please explain further the requirement for VBA in this case. I don't get it. I am happy to create a VBA solution.

Comment: The need is to look fór the result on a ";" delimited flat filé for the value with a macro. Sorry for nôt being clear om my need.

Comment: @Aslaam I still do not get it. Please update the question with what your data looks like as source and what you want it to look like after processing. Images are best.

Comment: here is an example. if the user types in february on Con cell (F,1) and 2015 in cell (F,2) that it will brings 70 from the flat file when pressing a button.

Comment: The objective is to transform the vlookup/conctenate formula into VBA code, and make it dynamic so that even if the table headers change (from rows to columns), it still brings the data from the flat file tab.

Comment: i am not allowed to add the screenshot unfortunately;

Comment: basically, i have a flat file with "Alan;manager;december;2014;300". the objective is to have a vba macro that does a look up of the concanetation of the rows and columns headers in the flat file, and brings the data "300".